# Can I analyze sensor data with Android Wear in background?

Tags: android, service, background-process, wear-os, android-sensors

for a experimental application I need to analyze accelerometer data of a smartwatch nearly all the time (I know that this will drain battery). On standard Android  would create a `Service` and a `WakeLock` to collect and process the data. Is this also possible with Android Wear?

Comment: its possible only but it will drain the battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my question: Yes it's possible like on a handheld-device. Just create a service that can run in the background and hold a wake-lock. You might also consider using [sensor batching](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UserInput) to save some battery power when using Android 4.4 or higher.